# How could you build a Neural Network with the same weights for different nodes in the same layer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorflow

The structure I'm imagining is like the one in the image bellow

[image]

where the output is softmax. For the hidden layer we would have

$$Z_1 = W_{11}^{[1]}x_2 + W_{12}^{[1]}x_2$$
$$Z_2 = W_{21}^{[1]}x_2 + W_{22}^{[1]}x_2$$
$$Z_3 = W_{11}^{[1]}x_3 + W_{12}^{[1]}x_4$$
$$Z_4 = W_{21}^{[1]}x_3 + W_{22}^{[1]}x_4$$

the same principle would apply to softmax. I came up with this idea by trying to create a neural network that behaved similar to a conditional logistic regression (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_logistic_regression).

I've done an implementation with Keras and Tensorflow that I believe will have the desired behavior, but I'm not sure.

```
class ConditionalNN(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, out_dim, l1 = 0, l2 = 0):
    super(ConditionalNN, self).__init__(name='')
    self.layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20,'tanh',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1_l2(l1=l1, l2=l2))
    self.layerL1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,'linear',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1_l2(l1=l1, l2=l2))
    self.layerL2 = tf.keras.layers.Softmax(axis=-2)
  def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
    x = self.layer1(input_tensor,training=training)
    x = self.layerL1(x,training=training)
    x = self.layerL2(x,training=training)
    return x
```

In this case, the input would be a 3D tensor like:

```
X = [
        [[x1,x2],
         [x3,x4]],
           ...
    ]
```

and the output would be something like:

```
Y = [[1,0],
     [0,1],
     [1,0],
      ...
    ]
```

Comment: Note that this kind of weight-sharing is an important aspect of convolutional neural networks, as I’ve written about [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/43166/25529) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/409172/247274).

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting idea and I think it makes sense to share weights.
I have not seen exactly what you described, but it is common to share weights in cases that two inputs has similar meaning. For example, in this [article](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/2959100.2959190) they use shared embeddings for the target video and video from the user history that has the same `video_id`. It is definitely possible to implement it in TensorFlow, if the two inputs has the same dimensions. The way to implement it is straight forward, create a weights matrix with dimension of (`feature_dimension`, `num_neuron`) and multiply the different inputs with the same matrix.